# Promoting a secondary plex to primary

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 install that uses Windows software RAID to mirror the drive. The primary drive is failing. I installed a new drive to the set and syncing is almost complete. Once the sync finishes, I want to promote the secondary plex to to the primary booting drive, break the set, and remove the failing drive from.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That turned out to be much easier than I expected, but let me back up. Doing research didn't turn up much, though looking for a boot.ini and not finding it provided the first real clue. In Vista builds and forward, boot.ini is replaced by Boot Configuration Data (BCD).

- In msconfig.exe, I set the default boot to secondary plex on Disk 1
- Reboot the server to confirm I was booting to the secondary plex
- Shut down the system
- Disconnect disk 0
- Boot the system to see what happens
- Log in to the desktop, open the Server Manager -> Storage -> Disk Manager
- Disk 0 is marked as missing
- I removed the mirrors

And the server is now waiting patiently for the new disk to arrive to create the new mirror.

I don't know if this is the right way to go about it but it seems to be working.

Update: Doing this will not change the friendly name of the secondary plex in the boot menu.

After doing the steps to promote the secondary plex, as outlined above, one must `BCDEdit.exe` using the `/set` operation to update the friendly name. This requires admin privileges on the server.

```
bcdedit /set {current} description "Windows Server 2008 R2 (Installed 1/6/2020)"
```